# Should I replace dependencies when upgrading Laravel (e.g. from 5.8 to 6)?

Tags: laravel-upgrade

I am working on upgrading Laravel from 5.8 to 6.

I have read the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade and many similar (mostly summary of documentation) online.

I have updated required versions for the packages that exist both on 5.8 and 6 installation:

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.2.5",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
    "laravel/framework": "^6.20",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.5"
},
"require-dev": {
    "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
    "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
    "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^3.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5.8"
},
```

This is ok but these two packages don't exist in Laravel 6 composer.json

```
"beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
"filp/whoops": "^2.0",
```

While there is one new package

```
"facade/ignition": "^1.16.15",
```

So I think, what I should do is to erase two packages in the old version and add the package in the new version, right?

Should I always do like this, I mean when I'm upgrading from 6 to 7 or 7 to 8 also?

Is it possible that I have any problem deleting packages in the previous versions?